# GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub... Resource not accessible by integration

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When I try to update the environment variables on an Azure DevOps release pipeline, I get the error below.

```
GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. GitHub returned the error 'Resource not accessible by integration'.
```

I am an admin on the GitHub repo.

In `Get sources`, it is currently configured for a GitHub OAuth Service Connection. Another user is able to update the environment variables. I am using GitHub (not enterprise).

Is this an Azure DevOps permission that I do not have?

[image: GitHub Could not create service hooks subscription Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. GitHub returned the error 'Resource not accessible by integration'.]

Comment: Just checking in to see if this issue persists, if you've found the workaround, you could feel free to add it as self-answer :)

Comment: I have a ticket open with Microsoft. When I hear back, I will update this thread

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with ADO tech support, it was discovered that we needed to remove the artifact and trigger definition from the release pipeline, and then re-add it. It is believed that there was cached service connection, and this updated the pointer to the correct service connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an Azure DevOps permission that I do not have?

This error message usually comes with `GitHub App installation token` service connection.

Go `Project Settings => Service Connections` to check the details of the specific service connection. If your service connection is GitHub App installation token based service connection, then it's expected behavior to meet that issue. Our team are working on adding that support so far, please check [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/896437/github-could-not-create-service-hooks-subscription.html).

[image]

**Workaround:**

1.Create a new service connection with OAuth/PAT method and use it in your pipeline. Since you're admin of the github repo, a [Github PAT](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) is more recommended.

2.If you have permission to the service connections and to the pipeline, this issue won't occur. Ask your Azure Devops project admin to via [manage security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secure-a-service-connection).

Comment: I got an update from Microsoft today. The issue was that the artifact was causing the pipeline to hang on to an old service connection. Removing and re-adding the artifact resolved the issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The linked ticket has been closed without a resolution noted. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue when attempting to enable CI for a build and found this article and after digging in deeper I discovered that the issue was the actual PAT we created for the automation. What we missed originally was enabling the admin:repo_hook for the repository. This took longer to uncover than it should have, but just wanted to add that, as removing and re-adding things didn't really do anything for us.